# No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have a UIViewController, from which I am trying to load 2 UITableViews.

I have a class named FirstTableViewController, which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.
I have tried the following code and it runs without errors or warnings

```
ViewController.m

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.
style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Now, I tried with this piece of code

```
ViewController.m

FirstTableViewController *tableView1 = [[FirstTableViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:tableView1];
```

And I get the following error message.

```
No visible @interface for 'FirstTableViewController' declares the selector 'initWithFrame:style:'
```

Why does this code works fine with `UITableView` class and fails with its subclass.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add a object of a controller as a subview on its own. Your class is inherited from uitableviewcontroller and you have made an object of this class and you are adding its own view as subview. that is wrong

Comment: I am adding it as a subview of the UIViewController, not UITableViewController

Comment: have set teh delegate and datasource to self for table.

Comment: No. I haven't set the delegate and datasource yet. Currently, I am trying to bring the 2 UITableViews into my VC's view.
From the VC's viewDidLoad, I am writing the above code. Here the self is VC, and I am trying to set the tableviews as the VC's view's subview.

Comment: table will not be visible without datasource and delegate implementation

Comment: from which class FirstTableViewController inherited?

Comment: FirstTableViewController is inherited from `UITableViewController` and I have edited the question.

Comment: then why you are adding a subview on self with its on class object. that is the wrong part